# Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle problem executing scripts

Tags: .net, oracle, sql-scripts

We are having trouble executing scripts that begin with BEGIN and are having multiple procedures or triggers with the aforementioned provider. Execution of those fails. Has anyone eperienced similiar problems?

Comment: Can you supply some more information, for example: error codes and/or sample code that always fails, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that is a 'feature' of MS DPO.

> The Oracle database does not support multiple transactions on a single connection—they are always scoped at the connection level. Accordingly, ODP.NET propagates a transaction to commands executed on the connection. The Microsoft provider requires you to explicitly assign the transaction to each command.
>
> (from [MSDN: Comparing the Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 Data Provider for Oracle and the Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971518.aspx#odpvsmsdp_topic11))

Consider using ODP.NET if you can.